# How to update a histogram when a slider is used?

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider

I want to build a histogram for the normal distribution and update the plot when the mean, standard deviation and sample size are changed; analogue to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006883/matplotlib-slider-for-parameters).

However, I struggle with the `update` function. In the example above

```
l, = plot(f(S, 1.0, 1.0))
```

and

```
def update(val):
    l.set_ydata(f(S, sGmax.val, sKm.val))
```

are used but **how would this have to be changed when a histogram is plotted**? So, I am not sure how to use the return values from `plt.hist`, pass them properly to `update` and then update the plot accordingly. Could anyone explain this?

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider


def update(val):
    mv = smean.val
    stdv = sstd.val
    n_sample = round(sn.val)
    # what needs to go here? how to replace xxx
    xxx(np.random.normal(mv, stdv, n_sample))
    plt.draw()


ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

m0 = -2.5
std0 = 1
n0 = 1000
n_bins0 = 20

nd = np.random.normal(m0, std0, n0)

# what needs to be returned here?
plt.hist(nd, normed=True, bins=n_bins0, alpha=0.5)

axcolor = 'lightgray'
axmean = plt.axes([0.25, 0.01, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)
axstd = plt.axes([0.25, 0.06, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)
axssize = plt.axes([0.25, 0.11, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)

smean = Slider(axmean, 'Mean', -5, 5, valinit=m0)
sstd = Slider(axstd, 'Std', 0.1, 10.0, valinit=std0)
sn = Slider(axssize, 'n_sample', 10, 10000, valinit=n0)

smean.on_changed(update)
sstd.on_changed(update)
sn.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to clear the axis and just replot the histogram. The other option, more in the spirit of `l.set_value` approach of the matplotlib slider [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/slider_demo.html) would be to generate the histogram data with numpy, use a bar chart and update this using `bar.set_height` and `bar.set_x` with a [rescale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984085/automatically-rescale-ylim-and-xlim-in-matplotlib#11039268) on the axis. The complete example is then:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider


def update(val):
    mv = smean.val
    stdv = sstd.val
    n_sample = round(sn.val)
    nd = np.random.normal(loc=mv, scale=stdv, size=n_sample)
    #Update barchart height and x values
    hist, bins = np.histogram(nd, normed=True, bins=n_bins0)
    [bar.set_height(hist[i]) for i, bar in enumerate(b)]
    [bar.set_x(bins[i]) for i, bar in enumerate(b)]
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    plt.draw()


def reset(event):
    mv.reset()
    stdv.reset()
    n_sample.reset()


ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

m0 = -2.5
std0 = 1
n0 = 1000
n_bins0 = 20

nd = np.random.normal(m0, std0, n0)
hist, bins = np.histogram(nd, normed=True, bins=n_bins0)
b = plt.bar(bins[:-1], hist, width=.3)

axcolor = 'lightgray'
axmean = plt.axes([0.25, 0.01, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)
axstd = plt.axes([0.25, 0.06, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)
axssize = plt.axes([0.25, 0.11, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)

smean = Slider(axmean, 'Mean', -5, 5, valinit=m0)
sstd = Slider(axstd, 'Std', 0.1, 10.0, valinit=std0)
sn = Slider(axssize, 'n_sample', 10, 10000, valinit=n0)

smean.on_changed(update)
sstd.on_changed(update)
sn.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

UPDATE:

Version using clear axis (`ax.cla()`) and redraw `ax.hist(...)`,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider


def update(val):
    mv = smean.val
    stdv = sstd.val
    n_sample = round(sn.val)
    nd = np.random.normal(loc=mv, scale=stdv, size=n_sample)
    #Redraw histogram
    ax.cla()
    ax.hist(nd, normed=True, bins=n_bins0, alpha=0.5)
    plt.draw()


def reset(event):
    mv.reset()
    stdv.reset()
    n_sample.reset()


ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

m0 = -2.5
std0 = 1
n0 = 1000
n_bins0 = 20

nd = np.random.normal(m0, std0, n0)
plt.hist(nd, normed=True, bins=n_bins0, alpha=0.5)

axcolor = 'lightgray'
axmean = plt.axes([0.25, 0.01, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)
axstd = plt.axes([0.25, 0.06, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)
axssize = plt.axes([0.25, 0.11, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)

smean = Slider(axmean, 'Mean', -5, 5, valinit=m0)
sstd = Slider(axstd, 'Std', 0.1, 10.0, valinit=std0)
sn = Slider(axssize, 'n_sample', 10, 10000, valinit=n0)

smean.on_changed(update)
sstd.on_changed(update)
sn.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Since you basically (need to) redraw everything in this solution (bars, ticks, ticklabels) there is no gain in prefering this over the `ax.clear()` `ax.hist()` solution. So you might want to give the code for the (easier) solution as well.

Comment: That seems to get the job done, thanks (upvoted)! If you could update the code according to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest suggestion, I would highly appreciate that.

Comment: I've added the example, redrawing may end up being slower if you're redrawing lots of bars, although I'm not sure if blitting works for a slider...

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks. Unfortunately, I cannot upvote twice :) I wait for a few more hours if something better shows up and if not accept it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the remove() function on the matplotlib.container.BarContainer object

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(9, 3.5))

_,_,q = ax.hist([1,2,3,4,4,4,3])
fig.canvas.draw()

q.remove()
_,_,q = ax.hist([1,2,3,4,1,1,3])
fig.canvas.draw()
```